# Using knockout to append css to Menu Bar in Asp.net MVC

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, so I have successfully used knockout to apply the css to my menu. The main idea is to back buttons enabled and disabled. so my main code is.

```
@using PresentationLayer.Areas.Resource.Models;
@model ChecklistItemIndex


<script src="~/Areas/Resource/Scripts/ChecklistItem.js"></script>

@section StatusArea {
    <h1 class="atlas-status-area-heading">Checklist Items</h1>
}

<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveChecklistItem", "ChecklistItem", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial", OnSuccess="saveComplete();"}, new { id = "ChecklistItemScreen"}))

{ 
    <div class="atlas-content-wrap">
        <div id="atlas-buttons">
            <div id="NewButton" data-bind="css: newButtonClass">
                @Ajax.ActionLink("New", "New", "ChecklistItem", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial", OnSuccess = "enterEditMode(true);" })
            </div>
            <div id="SaveButton" data-bind="css: saveButtonClass">
                @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save", "ChecklistItem", new { id = "" })
            </div>
            <div data-bind="css: deleteButtonClass">
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "ChecklistItem", new { id = "" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial", OnSuccess = "loadChecklistItems();" }, new { id = "DeleteButton" })
            </div>
            <div data-bind="css: cancelButtonClass">
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Cancel", "CancelEdit", "ChecklistItem", new { id = "" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial", OnSuccess = "leaveEditMode();" }, new { id = "CancelEditButton" })
            </div>
            <div data-bind="css: editButtonClass">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="atlas-content-left">
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td class="container-head-left"></td>
                    <td class="container-head-middle">Checklist Items</td>
                    <td class="container-head-right"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="container-body">
                        <div id="ChecklistItemList">
                            <table class="atlas-data-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            Description
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Default On
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Compulsory
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Item Type
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                @foreach (var item in Model.ChecklistItemSummarys)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Ajax.ActionLink(item.ChecklistItem, "DisplayChecklistItem", "ChecklistItem", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial" }, new { id = "ChecklistItemViewLink_" + item.Id})
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DefaultOn)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsSystem)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FieldItem)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="atlas-content-right">
            <div id="ViewEditPartial" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var viewModelToolbar =
{
    newButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonClass'),
    newActionClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonAction'),
    editButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.EditButtonClass'),
    saveButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.SaveButtonClass'),
    deleteButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.DeleteButtonClass'),
    cancelButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.CancelButtonClass'),
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModelToolbar);
```

my Controller to the page is

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var checklistItemIndex = new ChecklistItemIndex
        {
            ChecklistItemSummarys = new List<ChecklistItemSummary>
        {
            new ChecklistItemSummary
            {
                ChecklistItem = "Item 1",
                DefaultOn = true,
                FieldItem = true,
               Id =  Guid.NewGuid(),
               IsSystem = true
            },
            new ChecklistItemSummary
                    {
                ChecklistItem = "Item 2",
                DefaultOn = true,
                FieldItem = true,
               Id =  Guid.NewGuid(),
               IsSystem = true
            }
        },
            ToolbarSettings = new Toolbar

            {
                CancelButtonAction = "Cancel/",
                CancelButtonClass = "atlas-navigation-button-active",
                DeleteButtonAction = "Delete",
                DeleteButtonClass = "atlas-navigation-button-active",
                EditButtonAction = "Edit",
                EditButtonClass = "atlas-navigation-button-active",
                NewButtonAction = "New",
                NewButtonClass = "atlas-navigation-button-disabled",
                SaveButtonAction = "Save",
                SaveButtonClass = "atlas-navigation-button-active"

            }
        };
        return View(checklistItemIndex);
    }
```

I then want to be able to reapply new css to the same buttons when rendering my partial view, that is the detail of a checklist item. I followed the same concept on my partial view, applying the bindings, but just get the error  'JavaScript runtime error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.'  I appreciate why this might be, but can't find the best way to do this for my specific problem.

I am very new to knockout, and have read alot of the documentation, but the documentation seems to relate to more simple concepts, so am finding it hard to find the correct solution to use, as some solutions people have said are not the right way to go.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `cleanNode` before re-applying the model:

```
ko.cleanNode(document.body);
ko.applyBindings(viewModelToolbar);
```

**Update (as per your comment):**

Since you don't want to use `cleanNode`, you can update the existing view-model with the fresh data from the server:

```
var viewModelToolbar =
{
    newButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonClass'),
    newActionClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonAction'),
    editButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.EditButtonClass'),
    saveButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.SaveButtonClass'),
    deleteButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.DeleteButtonClass'),
    cancelButtonClass: ko.observable('@Model.ToolbarSettings.CancelButtonClass'),
};

var existingVm = ko.dataFor(document.body);

if (existingVm)
    {
    existingVm.newButtonClass(viewModelToolbar.newButtonClass);
    existingVm.newActionClass(viewModelToolbar.newActionClass);
    existingVm.editButtonClass(viewModelToolbar.editButtonClass);
    existingVm.saveButtonClass(viewModelToolbar.saveButtonClass);
    existingVm.deleteButtonClass(viewModelToolbar.deleteButtonClass);
    existingVm.cancelButtonClass(viewModelToolbar.cancelButtonClass);
    }
else
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelToolbar);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

Comment: This is one of the things that is not recommended to be used as it is actually part of knockouts internal Api, or so I read.  This is where I am a little stuck, as I don't know who to believe.

Comment: Personally, I don't consider it *internal* just like I don't consider `ko.unwrap` as such (both are not officially documented and `unwrap` is crucial for public use as well). Anyway, see my update.

Comment: Thank you, to be fair I have implemented the CleanNode as per your original post and it works brilliantly and there seems to be no issue with speed, I think it is cleaner than the alternative.  It wasn't that I don't want to use it, only I am very new to knockout, this is the first thing I have tried to do using it, and don't want to use things that other people deem 'incorrect' with the internet so full of opinions it is so hard to decipher who is correct.

Comment: If you're interested in a clean one-line solution, I can provide you one using the `ko.mapping` plugin.